# Incompatible UI Version - Black ops 2 Xbox 360

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops-2, xbox-system-link

Recently I got my hands on another copy of Black Ops 2, and decided to system link my two retail Xbox 360s together for old time's sake. I got the game to run on the second console, and connected to Xbox Live. I then proceeded to download the latest update from Live and by extension, Treyarch, thereafter proceeding to multiplayer.

The two Xboxs can see each other just fine. One can connect to the other with no issue whatsoever and vice versa. But the moment the game launches on any map, the connected console(client) gets kicked from the host, stating that there is an Incompatible UI Error, and thereafter refuses to connect back to the host.

This only happens in multiplayer, zombies work just fine. Adding to that, it happens on any map I try.

Both games are exactly the same version (44.1708.-1 IIRC) and are running on OEM Retail 360s with the latest firmware installed.

Is there any solution to this? All the forums and threads I've read online are relating to modded JTAG/RGH Consoles. I've looked on Se7enSins primarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a *LOT* of thinking and research, I've finally come up with a solution that resolves my incompatibility issues with my retail Xbox 360s.

Let me explain this as best as I can...

On the client console, the game version was 44.0.-1, interestingly enough, whereas the host console's game version was 44.1833.17. To bring the client console to the same version as the host, I downloaded and signed into my Xbox Live profile, and let the game sync with the game servers, before exiting and allowing others to join the party with their own, non-Xbox Live, profiles. Doing this brought the game version to exactly the same as the host, 44.1833.17.

From my understanding, 44.0.-1 is a form of error code from Treyarch Servers, and thus rejects the game's attempt to sync with mainline servers due to the profiles signed in being non-Live profiles. As such, this can be overridden temporarily by using the aforementioned solution.